# Xcode 8.1 Pre-processor Macros not highlighting code properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

As I said on the title, pre-processor macros are not working correctly on Xcode 8. In runtime, macros work fine, but before (while working), Xcode highlights the wrong block of code, and code completion does not work on the desire piece.

I'm using macros to differentiate between tvOS and iOS. I have my own Preprocessor Macros under build settings for each target, but I'm also using the SDK ones.

(Again, the app works fine when running and it uses the correct code, the issue is before running the app)

Example (this is under the iOS target, but it's the same under tvOS)

[image]

Thanks !

***Updated screenshot to reveal iOS target selected.***

Comment: In Xcode's title bar, just to the right of the run and stop buttons, is the proper target and destination selected?

Comment: @rmaddy Yes, the correct target is selected.

Comment: It would help if you updated your question with a screenshot showing what you have currently selected in Xcode. Please clip the screenshot to just the relevant part showing the target and destination.

Comment: @rmaddy question updated, thanks.

Comment: You nearly hid the important part to the right of your chosen target. It appears you've chosen "Generic iOS device". That's the important information here. With that chosen, "TARGET_OS_TV" shouldn't be true.